# I can not get nickName from users that currently added

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

i am new in asmack. i am writing a chat application and when i add a user by send him/her a subscription packet an he accept, i check openFire server nikename and other properties is ok for new user and mode is both.

but when i try to get friends data nickname is empty.

if i debug the code nickname receive correctly but in run mode can not?

code to receive friends :

```
 public static void getContacts(final Context ctx)
    {
    try
    {
        try
        {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();

        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        if(globalVars.friends == null)
            globalVars.friends = new ArrayList<globalVars.UserList>();
        globalVars.friends.clear();

        for(RosterEntry entry: entries)
        {
            String user = entry.getUser();
            String username = user.split("@")[0];
            Presence presence =  roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
            int status = R.drawable.offline;
            if(presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.available))
                status = R.drawable.online;
            //String fromto = presence.getFrom() + "   "+presence.getTo();
            globalVars.UserList ul = new UserList(username, status, globalVars.smallImageAddress(ctx, username));

            String wathsUp = "";

            try
            {
                if(presence.getStatus() != null)
                    wathsUp = presence.getStatus();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            ul.setComment(wathsUp);
            ul.setFriend(true);
            ul.setNikName(entry.getName());

            globalVars.friends.add(ul);
        }
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vCard for setting nickname or other details of a user.
Use this code for getting Vcard information from a jid

```
VCard mVCard = new VCard();

mVCard.load(your xmppconnection,user jid);
String name = mVCard.getNickName();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on this matter: `VCard` `load()` method is now deprecated.

Instead you can use this method:

```
/**
 * retrieves an user VCard
 *
 * @param userJid the user jid
 * @return the VCard object
 */
public VCard getVCard(String userJid) {
    VCard vCard = null;
    VCardManager vCardManager = VCardManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    boolean isSupported;
    try {
        //remove resource name if necessary
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userJid) && userJid.contains("/")) {
            userJid = userJid.split("/")[0];
        }
        isSupported = vCardManager.isSupported(userJid);
        if (isSupported)  // return true
            vCard = vCardManager.loadVCard(userJid);
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iAE) {
        iAE.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vCard;
}
```

As you can see, the method checks if the user understands the vCard-XML format and exchange. If it does, it returns the VCard.

Then just retrieve the user nickname from VCard.